# Load custom header with StackNavigator on React Native

Tags: react-native

I had a `Header` component that I used as a static appbar in React Native. Now I'm trying to include a `StackNavigator` to be easier to manage the transitions between screens.

My problem is that I can't include my `Header` component in the `StackNavigator` header. My current code and result are shown below:

```
const APPBAR_HEIGHT = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 44 : 56;

const GiftNavigator = StackNavigator(
{
  All: {
    screen: GiftListSection,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarLabel: 'All',
    }
  },
  Reclaim: {
    screen: GiftReclaimSection,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarLabel: 'Reclaim',
    }
  }
}, {
  headerMode: 'float',
    header: (
        <View style={{ height: APPBAR_HEIGHT }}>
            <Header />
        </View>
    )
});
```

[image: Screenshot from the Header loaded]

Note that the `Header` is not loaded. It is just a blank space. How can I load my `Header` component to the `StackNavigator` header? If I load my own `Header`, will it contain the back button from the default Navigator header?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
export default class YourScreen extends Component {

  static navigationOptions = {
    header: <YourHeader/>,
  };
  ...
}
```

or:

```
const GiftNavigator = StackNavigator(
{
  All: {
    screen: GiftListSection,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarLabel: 'All',
      header: <YourHeader/>,
    }
  },
  Reclaim: {
    screen: GiftReclaimSection,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarLabel: 'Reclaim',
      header: <YourHeader/>,
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this can help you!

Answer (score 3):

You can hide the default react navigation header entirely by using the `headerMode: 'none'` option and handle header on your own for each component.

Or you could use the `header` property and load your own custom header component:

```
navigationOptions: {
  header: props => <CustomHeader {...props} />,
},
```